# How do I split a string when a letter comes after a digit c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I want to split my string when a letter comes after a number, but without getting rid of the number itself. For example, ABC123CW23F1 should output as ABC123, CW23, and F1. I've attempted using String.Spilt

```
string testString = "ABC123CW23F1";
Console.WriteLine(testString);
string[] new_String = testString.Split(new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3' });
for (int i = 0; i < new_String.Length; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(new_String[i]);
}
```

But this outputs ABC a few empty lines, and then CW Then some empty Lines, then F. How do I make it not that? Please Help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expected output suggests that you want to split whenever a digit precedes and a letter proceeds.  You may split on the following regex, which uses lookarounds:

```
(?<=\d)(?=[A-Z])
```

Here is a code sample:

```
string str = "A4HM23D9";
string[] split = Regex.Split(str, @"(?<=\d)(?=[A-Z])");
Console.WriteLine(split[0] + " " + split[1] + " " + split[2]);

A4 HM23 D9
```

### Demo

Comment: That's very elegant!

Comment: @Sach Regex lookarounds.  Don't leave home without them :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. Now I'm curious, is it possible to do this with multiple parameters. Like split it when a letter comes after a number (like you did) and also (just for example) whenever a symbol (ex. '?') follows a letter? I don't need this for my code, but it now has me thinking

Comment: Yes, you may use an alternation in the regex.  For example:

Comment: `(?<=\d)(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=\?)`